# minimize the regex for url

Tags: javascript

Can you please help me with the regex which matches all condition below except last one and not the section articles.i.e last one should not match as it doesnt have / at the end.

It should match Home and section pages (Because they have / at end of their url).

```
http://www.post.co.uk/
http://www.post.co.uk/news/
http://www.post.co.uk/news/celebrity-news/
```

and not

```
http://www.post.co.uk/news/herjerher/jewkrjewrj
```

Note that the last url doesn't have backslash `/` at the end of the URL

```
(http|https):\/\/.*\/[a-zA-Z'-]+\/[a-zA-Z'-]+\/?$
^(http|https):\/\/www.post.co.uk\/?$
^(http|https):\/\/www.post.co.uk\/[a-zA-Z'-]+\/?
```

Comment: why should the last one not match?

Comment: So the last one should not match because, ?????  oh, right.. it has `and not ` at the start.  Correct?

Comment: Basically I wast to match the section pages so which ends with "/". Article pages doesnt end with /

Comment: Try `url.slice(-1) != "/"`

Comment: Thanks. Need a single regex in JS which works for all conditions

Comment: @virgopassionate Have you tried 3 answers shared already?

Answer (score 0):

```
/^http:\/\/www\.post\.co\.uk\/([^\/]+\/){0,}$/
```

That means:

```
^: The word starts with
$: The word ends with
\/: Stands for /
[^\/]: All chars without /
[^\/]+: At least one char which is not /
([^\/]+\/){0,}: The group of at least one char which is not / and a / is availabe for at least 0 times
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I modified the JS code and it worked. :)

Comment: @virgopassionate If an answer is usefull for you, it would be kind to push the arrow up button :-)

Comment: @virgopassionate: are you familiar with accepting answers here? It is not mandatory, but it is a good way to thank people who have helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [URL constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)

```
var fnIsValidURL = url => {
  try{ new URL( url ); } catch( e ) { return false; } 
  return true;
};

var hasSlashAtEnd = url => url.slice( -1 ) == "/";
```

Now use them as

```
var url = "http://www.post.co.uk/news/celebrity-news/";
if ( fnIsValidURL( url ) && hasSlashAtEnd( url ) )
{
   alert( "valid" );
}
else
{
   alert( "invalid" );
}
```

**Note**

- Check the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL#Browser_compatibility) of `URL` before using this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
/^http:\/\/www[.].*\/$/
```

The dollar is specifying the exact char that has to be before the end